# expect script sending password before prompt

Tags: ssh, password, expect

I have written a small `expect` script for automatic ssh to remote server. But sometimes my `expect` script don't work. Actually it sends password before password prompt. Here is my script

```expect
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set password xyzzys
# now connect using ssh
set host [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh vivek.gagrani@$host
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "$password\r"
send -- "\r"
interact
```

When running this script I see below output sometimes:

```
spawn ssh vivek.gagrani@bvdev429
xyzzys         ----> password sent before asking

vivek.gagrani@bvdev429's password:
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Does it take 10 seconds before the password is sent? Because that's the default timeout for non-matching patterns.

The default mode for patterns for the `expect` command is "glob". glob patterns don't treat dots and parentheses specially.

If you want to specify a regular expression, use

```
expect -re "(.*)assword:"
```

Comment: sorry there is small mistake in my script, I have corrected it. Yes it takes 10 seconds before the password is sent. Can we increase this timeout?

Comment: You can increase the timeout: `set timeout 60` or disable the timeout altogether: `set timeout -1`

Comment: To see if the pattern is matching and to figure out why not, run your script with `expect -d script.exp` to enable verbose debug output. That will show the exact text the pattern is trying to match.